# React app with NET7 api - url rewrite on one site

Tags: reactjs, .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-hosting

I'm trying to host React app with NET7 api on one IIS site. On root folder there is such file structure

- index.html
- other files js/css
- api/my-app.exe (in subfolder api there are all .NET api binaries)

Api works because I request to */api/status* healthcheck methods and it returns 200. But when I request to */index.html* I get *404 (NotFound)*.

Do you know how should I setup rewrite rules or configure it in other way to get **index.html** file

There is my web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\api\my-app.exe" arguments=".\api\my-app.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\iis-logs\" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
        
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Stop process React routes" stopProcessing="true">
        TODO: how to write rule to get index.html file ??
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why not put the HTML and JS where it belongs in an ASP.NET project? Which is the wwwroot folder.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen JS/CSS files should be downloadable, binaries not, so I don't put it together. I affraid little mess while keeping all files in one folder

Comment: Why would the binaries have anything to do with downloading? There’s no mess if you put the files where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen all binaries are in API subfolder, in root there are htmls. They are located as I want. I don't know how to handle html, js and css to be access by url and every request with api in address should be handled by dotnet napp

Comment: Putting everything in a single IIS site is a bad habit (404s are caused by your ASP.NET Core routing right now), if you are not using the SPA template. No matter how much you want that approach to work, extra settings are needed. Set up two IIS sites to host React and .NET bits separately, and then you can use a reverse proxy to unify the URLs. OutOfProcess mode is also a bad choice and hurt performance.

Comment: @LexLi There's no extra configuration needed, nor is there nothing bad in serving HTML/JS/CSS content from within an ASP.NET application. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Jacek You should not go with "as I want" but as it should be done. Put the ASP.NET application regularly to be run in IIS and then you can have all the web content in wwwroot folder, as it is supposed to be. All API requests are routed within the ASP.NET application to the correct handlers and all content requests are served as static files. If it's not an ASP.NET application but something else then the answer is different. Why complicate things?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Only if the developer starts with the default SPA project templates, there is less configuration needed, but you can assume a lot of the developers didn't follow that (and VS2022 also moves to separate JS/TS projects out). The SPA template approach has its disadvantages, so I won't say that's "nothing bad".

Comment: Steps to deploy a React application on an IIS server: https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the rewrite rules in the web.config file. Here's how to set up rewrite rules to serve a React app's index.html file and other static resources:

```
<rewrite>
         <rules>
             <rule name="Serve React App" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url=".*" />
                 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
             </rule>
         </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

You need to adjust the paths and configurations according to your specific project structure and requirements.